# Cleanest way to toggle a boolean variable in Java?

Tags: java, boolean

Is there a better way to negate a boolean in Java than a simple if-else?

```
if (theBoolean) {
    theBoolean = false;
} else {
    theBoolean = true;
}
```

Comment: oh nice, I was about to ask the same question, although my question would've been specific to javascript/as3, or ECMAScript in general I suppose... which will easily be covered by this question.

Comment: What if there is no ! operator ??

Answer (score 596, accepted):

```
theBoolean = !theBoolean;
```

Comment: That's...really obvious—oops! Don't know why I didn't think of it. Thanks.

Comment: !Boolean seems like a natural choice - maybe in the future.

Comment: @ypnos: `!!bool == !(!(bool)) == bool`.

Comment: @ChristofferHammarström By that logic, then shouldn't --integer == -(-(integer)) == integer    ?

Comment: @user515655 - The language defines a `--` operator (actually, two of them, along with two `++` operators), but doesn't define a `!!` operator. If you want `-(-(integer))` you can use white space between the two `-` characters. But `!!` parses as two `!` operators regardless of white space.

Comment: In that case, what about `bool!!`

Answer (score 182):

```
theBoolean ^= true;
```

Fewer keystrokes if your variable is longer than four letters

**Edit**: code tends to return useful results when used as Google search terms. The code above doesn't. For those who need it, it's ***bitwise XOR*** as [described here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/Java-Bitwise-Operators).

Comment: Brevity is the soul of wit.

Comment: now I get to offhandedly name-drop (syntax-drop?) XOR to look cool in front of my programmer friends. Your answer ought to be merged with the chosen one, together they are pure perfection.

Comment: @ScottStanchfield Such people should learn it. It's not hard at all, it's no hack, and not knowing it often leads to crappy code as e.g. the one this question. This is a real blow up - five lines using the standard conventions!

Comment: Think about "should learn it" vs "trying to understand what's going on when you have a day to fix a bug". Yes, XOR is cool here, but the number of people I've mentioned XOR to who say "huh?" is staggering. You should always code for the maintenance programmer, making his job as easy as you can, because no matter how well the code is written, reading someone else's code really sucks.

Comment: But... this allows you to parametrize the negation :) `theBoolean ^= shouldBeNegated;`

Comment: [This operation is also 12% faster](http://jsperf.com/boolean-toggling) than other versions like `theBoolean = !theBoolean;` or `theBoolean = theBoolean ? false : true;`

Comment: @BlaineKasten apparently not anymore. Everything is running at equal speed (FF43, Ubuntu 15 64-Bit)
EDIT: It's 50% slower for me on Chrome 47, while ternary has a speed of "infinity".

Comment: If you declare a boolean constant with value `true` in a class `T` and you call it `t`, then you can save one additional keystroke: `myVal ^= T.t;`. Not to speak of a static import... `myVal ^= t;`... Unlimited powah!

Comment: @BlaineKasten - On Chrome 55 on OS X, this is the slowest by 53%. Interestingly, the ternary expression is the fastest.

Answer (score 54):

## There are several

**The "obvious" way** (for most people)

```
theBoolean = !theBoolean;
```

**The "shortest" way** (most of the time)

```
theBoolean ^= true;
```

**The "most visual" way** (most uncertainly)

```
theBoolean = theBoolean ? false : true;
```

## Extra: Toggle and use in a method call

```
theMethod( theBoolean ^= true );
```

Since the assignment operator always returns what has been assigned, this will toggle the value via the bitwise operator, and then return the newly assigned value to be used in the method call.

Comment: Wrap the implementation in a function/method called toggle and then there's almost no way to confuse it.

Comment: @Reiner: For `C` definately, but in `Java` it is not allowed to mix boolean and integer (also things like `while(1)` are not possible in Java).

Comment: @Lambage: True, but on the downside you can't toggle a boolean by simply passing it, since it is not possible to pass primitives by reference in Java. You would have to reassign the result of the method to your variable, or otherwise create a wrapper class for the boolean.

Comment: The "obvious way" above get flagged by SONAR with - Inner assignments should be avoided.

Answer (score 8):

This answer came up when searching for "java invert boolean function". The example below will prevent certain static analysis tools from failing builds due to branching logic. This is useful if you need to invert a boolean and haven't built out comprehensive unit tests ;)

```
Boolean.valueOf(aBool).equals(false)
```

or alternatively:

```
Boolean.FALSE.equals(aBool)
```

or

```
Boolean.FALSE::equals
```

Comment: I like the fact that you could pass `Boolean.FALSE::equals` to a mapping function instead of writing a little lambda

Answer (score 2):

If you use Boolean NULL values and consider them false, try this:

```
static public boolean toggle(Boolean aBoolean) {
    if (aBoolean == null) return true;
    else return !aBoolean;
}
```

If you are not handing Boolean NULL values, try this:

```
static public boolean toggle(boolean aBoolean) {
   return !aBoolean;
}
```

These are the *cleanest* because they show the intent in the method signature, are easier to read compared to the *!* operator, and can be easily debugged.

Usage

```
boolean bTrue = true
boolean bFalse = false
boolean bNull = null

toggle(bTrue) // == false
toggle(bFalse) // == true
toggle(bNull) // == true
```

Of course, if you use *Groovy* or a language that allows extension methods, you can register an extension and simply do:

```
Boolean b = false
b = b.toggle() // == true
```

Comment: Good approach, but not totally unambiguous (imho). For someone using/reading just "toggle(..)" might think, calling the method (without assigning it again to the variable) might already toggle the underlying variable. It is obvious to us right now seeing the code, but in real life might be quite hard to debug. A better method name might be "opposite" or possibly "negation", to make this somewhat more obvious; or use the first approach with an object `Boolean` and really toggle it within the method (but still somewhat ambiguous).

Answer (score 1):

The class `BooleanUtils` supportes the negation of a boolean. You find this class in [commons-lang:commons-lang](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3)

```
BooleanUtils.negate(theBoolean)
```

Comment: That doesn't actually change the variable. BooleanUtils are mainly meant for good handling of null, otherwise you don't need them.

Answer (score 1):

```
Boolean original = null; // = Boolean.FALSE; // = Boolean.TRUE;
Boolean inverse = original == null ? null : !original;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ternary operator to have a clean conditional statement

```
theBoolean = theBoolean?false:true;
```

I believe this to be the most efficient toggle statement without the use of any fancy functions.

Comment: This came to my head suddenly one day. Upvote is appreciated.

Answer (score -2):

If you're not doing anything particularly professional you can always use a Util class. Ex, a util class from a project for a class.

```
public class Util {


public Util() {}
public boolean flip(boolean bool) { return !bool; }
public void sop(String str) { System.out.println(str); }

}
```

then just create a Util object 
`Util u = new Util();`
and have something for the return `System.out.println( u.flip(bool) );`

If you're gonna end up using the same thing over and over, use a method, and especially if it's across projects, make a Util class. Dunno what the industry standard is however. (Experienced programmers feel free to correct me)

Comment: Downvoted. 1. It doesn't improve readability. 2. It does add a serious runtime overhead. 3. Util classes are generally a code smell.

Answer (score -5):

Before:

```java
boolean result = isresult();
if (result) {
    result = false;
} else {
    result = true;
}
```

After:

```java
boolean result = isresult();
result ^= true;
```

Comment: Who ever has  down voted? Can you please explain reason also?

Comment: Two main reasons I can think of why someone might have downvoted you:
1) Thread necromancy (_come on! the question was asked 7(!) years ago!_) & your answer doesn't bring anything new to the table; 2) The voter expected something "cleaner" (_read: shorter_) - AaronMaenpaa's answer is a prime example of this.

Comment: after: boolean result = !isresult();