# Toggle return value for CheckboxPreference onClick

Tags: java, android, android-preferences, checkboxpreference

I need to find a way to toggle the return value when clicking my CheckboxPreference. I have already set a key in my settings.xml. The click works fine, I'm just curious about how to return a new value upon each click.

```
final Preference disableRemixingPref = (Preference) findPreference("disableRemixing");
        disableRemixingPref.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {

                // I don't always want to return true here. Basically, on every click I want to return the opposite of what the selection was before.

                return true;
            }

        });
```

Comment: Why don't you post and accept your own answer? It might help someone in the future.

Comment: @PaulHicks I have to wait 2 days before I can accept my own answer. I probably will at that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to figure it out myself rather quickly. Did a few searches on toggling Boolean values: [Cleanest way to toggle a boolean variable in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224311/cleanest-way-to-toggle-a-boolean-variable-in-java)

```
    final Preference disableRemixingPref = (Preference) findPreference("disableRemixing");
    disableRemixingPref.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {

        boolean toggle = false;
        public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
            disableRemixingPref.setSelectable(true);

            // Disable remixing by default
            ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
            currentUser.put("remixByDefault", toggle);
            currentUser.saveInBackground();

            toggle = !toggle;
            return toggle;
        }

    });
```